# CakePHP looking for column that doesn't exist

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

So I removed a column from my users table as my application no longer uses it anywhere. I've made sure that there are no references anywhere in my code to this specific column. Yet, when I try to log in to the application I get `Error: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'Users.registered_through' in 'field list'`.

I'm in debug mode, and I've made sure that there is nothing in my cache folder.

Just wondering why the application is still looking for a column that I have removed, and what I do to fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> why the application is still looking for a column that I have removed

By default Cakephp [uses the file system](https://github.com/cakephp/app/blob/master/config/app.default.php#L107-L121) for caching database schema data, if a different cache store is used, deleting the cache files won't have any effect.

> what I do to fix this?

A cli is provided, the [ORM Cache Shell](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/console-and-shells/orm-cache.html), which can be used to clear or rebuild the relevant cached data:

```
# Clear all metadata
bin/cake orm_cache clear

# Clear a single table
bin/cake orm_cache clear articles
```